# Using VBA to move a folder already open in Windows Explorer: Path/File Access Error

Tags: vba, directory

I have written Excel VBA code to identify the containing folder of an open Word document, move the containing folder and its contents.
If I have the folder open in Windows Explorer, the code throws an error (Path/File access error)
If I have navigated out of the containing folder it works fine.
I need for the code to run whether or not the containing folder is open in Windows Explorer

```
Sub Mover()

Dim OldFolder As String
Dim NewFolder As String
Dim wdApp As Object

Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

OldFolder = "\\X-ns1\Test\Open\" & Replace(wdApp.ActiveDocument.Name, ".docx", "")

NewFolder = "\\X-ns1\Test\Closed and imported\" & Replace(wdApp.ActiveDocument.Name, ".docx", "")

wdApp.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Application.Quit

Name OldFolder As NewFolder

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with folders. The problem is the open word doc. When you open a file that exists in a folder a connection is made between the open file and the folder that it was opened in. There are certain events (renaming said folder) that are locked down until that file is closed.
First run your code to quit the word file and you should not have any issues.

Comment: I've tried replacing wdApp.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Application.Quit with wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close
I see your point, however, it still remains that my code runs fine if I've navigated away from the containing folder of the Word document.

Comment: OK, It may be a focus thing. Try leaving the folder open but move the focus to something else, say another icon. Then run your code.

Comment: Any success with this?